# Movie ticket price homework,how to conbine two kind of tickets label's price?

Tags: c#, new-operator

The correct function,should be Lb1SumF PLUS Lb2SumF equal Lb3SumF,but when i input the number of ticket, my program didn't display the correct function of it.

Here's [a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucwzu.jpg)! is the design.

Here is my code.

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        TX1.Text = "0";
        TX1.Focus();
        TX2.Text = "0";
        textBox2.Text = "10000";
    }

    private void TX1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int sum;
            sum = Convert.ToInt32(TX1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(Lb1PriceF.Text);
            Lb1SumF.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);

        }
        catch
        {
            Lb1SumF.Text = "";
        }
    }
    private void TX2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int sum;
            sum = Convert.ToInt32(TX2.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(Lb2PriceF.Text);
            Lb2SumF.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);


        }
        catch
        {
            Lb2SumF.Text = "";
        }
    }
    private void Lb3SumF_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int summ;
            summ = Convert.ToInt32(Lb1SumF.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(Lb2SumF.Text);
            Lb3SumF.Text = Convert.ToString(summ);
        }
        catch
        {
            Lb3SumF.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are getting the numbers for lb1, lb2 but never updating lb3, after you update lb1 or lb2 you must update lb3 also, lb3=lb1total+lb2total

Comment: You should have a button to sum the individual prices. You should have a global variable to save the converted total price in a numeric type field. You should have a function to sum the 3 global variables to set the total.

Comment: Maybe getting error while converting variables (Convert.ToInt32(Lb2SumF.Text)) and because it's in a try-catch you can't see it?